# How to take file name from yt-dlp and use it as ffmpeg output file name?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, bash-scripting, pipe, yt-dlp

I'm trying to get the output name to be the same as the input name while using the pipe command in ffmpeg.

**Example:**

The file is called `1-Minute Audio Test for Stereo Speakers & Headphones [2ZrWHtvSog4].m4a`. I'm trying to get the **output filename** to be **automatically** the same as the **input file name** but with the `.mp3` extension.

So the final name should be `1-Minute Audio Test for Stereo Speakers & Headphones [2ZrWHtvSog4].mp3` without having to type it in manually.

**Example:**

```
yt-dlp -o - -f 139 --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args '-d ./ -x 10' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 | ffmpeg -i pipe: -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 8000 -ac 1 -ar 8000 test_audio.mp3
```

These commands create a file called `test_audio.mp3` I'm trying to get it to be `1-Minute Audio Test for Stereo Speakers & Headphones [2ZrWHtvSog4].mp3` without having to type it in.

I'm not sure how to pipe / get the file name variable from the input file to the output file of ffmpeg.

**My thoughts were to:**

1. Get the file name from yt-dlp and place that in a variable.
2. Use that variable as the output file name with ffmpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me.

```
yt-dlp -o - -f 139 --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args '-d ./ -x 10' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 | ffmpeg -i pipe: -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 8000 -ac 1 -ar 8000 -f mp3 "$(basename "$(yt-dlp -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 | sed 's/[\/:*?"<>|]/_/g')").mp3"
```

Explanation:

The basename command is used to extract the base name from the URL. It retrieves the video title using yt-dlp -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 and then replaces any characters that are not allowed in file names with underscores using sed 's/[/:*?"<>|]/_/g'.

The $(...) syntax is used to execute a command and use its output as part of the larger command.

$(basename "$(yt-dlp -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrWHtvSog4 | sed 's/[/:*?"<>|]/_/g')").mp3 is the resulting file name with the .mp3 extension added.